# Find List Item in List of HashMaps

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `List<Map<String, Object>>` and want to find an item by its id and then return a property of that HashMap. Let me illustrate this with an example:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> test = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    
var first = new HashMap<String, Object>();
first.put("Id", "4711");
first.put("State", "Ok");
    
var second = new HashMap<String, Object>();
second.put("Id", "4712");
second.put("State", "Not Ok");
    
test.add(first);
test.add(second);
```

How would I search the list of hashmaps where `Id` is 4712 and get its `State`?

I know I can do this by manually iterating over the list. However, I would prefer this to be done with streams.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're struggling with. Just iterate over the list, check the value of `get("Id")` for each map and if it matches your search pattern do `get("State")` on the same map. Using streams you could do something like `test.stream().filter(m -> "4712".equals(m.get("Id"))).map(m -> m.get("State")).findAny()`.

Comment: Sorry might have forgotten that I want this done doing streams and not by manual iteration. Thanks though

Comment: Well, I provided an example using streams but you might have a different understandings of what streams would do in contrast to "manual iteration". Care to elaborate on your understanding and why you need to use streams?

Comment: Streams are a lot more efficient compared to just iterating through a list. Secondly, it is a lot easier to read and uses less code. The example you provided helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @TomelSafadi: streams are in no way automatically "more efficient". In fact for many simple cases manually iterating produces fewer objects/allocations and is more efficient. Streams *can* be more efficient than naive manual iteration when they can optimize some actions away, but that usually doesn't apply to the simple uses mostly seen on this site. The readability of streams is also debatable ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joachim Sauer wrote in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75458590/find-list-item-in-list-of-hashmaps#comment133139652_75458590), just because some aspect of the Java programming language is newer (and appears "cooler") doesn't mean it is better. As the saying goes:

> The right tool for the right job.

Anyway, the below code produces the desired result from the input provided in your question.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> test = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        var first = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        first.put("Id", "4711");
        first.put("State", "Ok");
        var second = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        second.put("Id", "4712");
        second.put("State", "Not Ok");
        test.add(first);
        test.add(second);

        Object val = test.stream() // Every element in stream has type Map<String, Object>
                         .filter(m -> "4712".equals(m.get("Id")))
                         .findFirst() // returns Optional<Map<String, Object>>
                         .get() // throws 'NoSuchElementException' if nothing found
                         .get("State"); // i.e. java.util.Map#get
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

Running the above code displays:

```
Not Ok
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the get method and pass "4712" as key.

See Java documentation, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-